# How get parametrized and named instance from play guice injector

Tags: playframework, guice

I have a test, where I provides binding for typed `ICache<String, String>` with named annotation:

```
public class UserControllerTest extends WithApplication {

    @Override
    protected Application provideApplication() {
        return new GuiceApplicationBuilder()
          .overrides(new AbstractModule() {
              @Override
              protected void configure() {
                  bind(new TypeLiteral<ICache<String, String>>() {
                  })
                    .annotatedWith(Names.named("SessionsCache"))
                    .toProvider(() -> new GuavaCache(1500, TimeUnit.MILLISECONDS));
              }
          }).build();
    }


    @Test
    public void someTest() throws Exception {
        final ICache<String, String> sessionCache = app.injector().instanceOf(
            new BindingKey<ICache>(ICache.class, Option.apply(new QualifierInstance(Names.named("SessionsCache"))))
        );
    }

}
```

And testable class (**upd2**):

```
public class UserController extends Controller {

    private final ICache<String,String> sessionsCache


    @Inject
    public UserController(@Named("SessionsCache") ICache<String,String> sessionsCache) {
       this.sessionsCache = sessionsCache;
    }
}
```

But it gives me error:

`No implementation for cache.ICache annotated with @com.google.inject.name.Named(value=SessionsCache) was bound.`

What's i'm doing wrong?

**upd**

I found [discuss](https://github.com/playframework/playframework/issues/3422), that play don't support generic type injection - it's guice feature. But question still open...

Comment: What does the call-site look like? Also, I would try to stick with the `javax.inject` types rather than the guice-specific for compatibility.

Comment: @rethab, How I understand, my mistake, that i mix guice with play's di agnostic layer. And possible solution - abandon generic type injection and use play dl api. Or using guice directly - but i think it's more bad solution.